# How to reconstruct a file from base64 encoding?

Tags: python, base64, decode, encode

I'm trying to encode a file with base64, then send the encoded data and reconstruct the file on the other end. For example, I want to open a .png file located on my desktop, encode it, then decode it and save a new .png in a different directory.

I was referred to use the following article, but I receive an error as you can see below: https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/convert-image-to-string-in-python/

```
import base64

with open('path_to_file', 'rb') as imageFile:
    x = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

fh = open('imageToSave.png', 'wb')
fh.write(x.decode('base64'))
fh.close()

File "directory", line 7, in <module>
    fh.write(x.decode('base64'))
LookupError: 'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

I tried looking for similar problems on stackoverflow, but I did not understand other solutions and was unable to implement them in my case. If there is a better way of accomplishing this task, please let me know.

Comment: `str.decode()` no more support `'base64'` in python3.

Comment: This is one of those cases where old python 2 examples don't work with python 3. In python 3 you have to keep track of `str` and `bytes` objects and use the `base64` or `binascii` encoders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use `decode`, instead of [`base64.b64decode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html)?

Because that works fine:

```
>>> base64.b64encode(b"foo")
b'Zm9v'
>>> base64.b64decode('Zm9v')
b'foo'
```

Or, in your case:

```
import base64

with open('path_to_file', 'rb') as imageFile:
    x = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

fh = open('imageToSave.png', 'wb')
fh.write(base64.b64decode(x))
fh.close()
```

There is a difference between Python 2 and 3 here though. `str.decode('base64')` seems to work in Python 2, but not in 3.

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed the article, but I did not question the fh.write statement.

Comment: Yes in Python 2 .encode() and .decode() accepted any codec, in Python 3 you can't use .encode / .decode with bytes -> bytes codecs, so things like bz2 or uu or base64 don't work anymore, you have to use the proper / dedicated APIs.